# Schedule task with cygwin script

Tags: linux, bash, windows, cygwin, scheduling

In fact I have installed cygwin on windows server 2016, and my scripts run perfectly inside bash terminal.

Now I want to schedule my scripts to run per day using windows task scheduler.

So I have created a new task:

Action: start a program

Program/Script: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe

Add arguments: "/home/administrator/myscript.sh"

And finally I triggered it everyday.

But it's not working, last run result I get (0x41303)

It's the first time I'm using task scheduler with cygwin, otherwise crontab is much easier.

Can you guys help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "/home/administrator/myscript.sh"
```

But, you might need to set some environment things, so you might want to test above first from the command-prompt.

Comment: Hi, worked perfectly.

on arguments: -c "home/administrator/myscript.sh"

Thanks